# DPDK Pktgen -- interpret output

Tags: network-programming, dpdk

I'm trying to understand DPDK and I'm new to these performance tools. Any help help would be greatly appreciated.

I've setup DPDK and Pktgen on my Virtual Box Ubuntu VM with two host-only adapters. Those two NICs are managed by DPDK.

[image: dpdk_nic_bind.py output]

When I run the command

```
pktgen -c -x01 -n 3 -- -P -m "[1:3].0, [2:4].1"
```

I see the below screen

[image]

But, I do not see any values getting changed. It seems to be the same regardless of changes to the command. How do I interpret this values in the picture? How do I pump up traffic on one of the adapters and measure its performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pktgen is waiting for commands, hence the `Pktgen>` prompt.

For instance, to start sending packet on port 0 with the default settings you can use `start 0`.

You can also use `help` for help. The list of available command is also explained here: https://pktgen.readthedocs.org/en/latest/commands.html

EDIT: (see comments)

The core mask should be at least `-c 0x1f`, to have 5 cores availables

Comment: I tried start 0 but nothing happens. I am not sure if the IP addresses mentioned in the above screenshot. I tried with "set ip src". Nothing happens after that too.

Comment: The moment I make the interfaces DPDK enable, kernel will lose them. Can I still use the IP addresses that were associated with it before they were enabled in DPDK?

Comment: It is perfectly normal that the kernel lose them, those NIC are now managed by DPDK using user-space drivers, the kernel cannot  sees them anymore. Therefore the IP set previously by the kernel are irrelevant now. Here, the IP corresponds only to what Pktgen will put in the packets it sends. Also the is maybe a typo in your command line, -x01 shouldn't be 0x01?

Comment: -m "[1:3].0, [2:4].1" implies you have 5 cores available (0 to 4), but it does not seems to be the case according to your -c option

Comment: Yes, I've 6 cores. "-x01" is just a typo here. Regarding the IP addresses, I'm not sure where Pktgen is picking them up from. I tried with "set ip src" but that does not seem to be of any affect.

Comment: You're correct. Changing the cores to 5 worked: -c 0x1f. Thank you so much.